# Calculating differences in logs

Tags: r, difference, stock

ive stock prices and I want to calculate the gains

MLB.Prices

```
MLB.Prices
2008-01-01      40.72
2009-01-01      48.66
2010-01-01      47.23
2011-01-01      44.45
2012-01-01      41.82
2013-01-01      44.61
2014-01-01      55.22
```

From this, I want to calculate the gains as differences in logs log(P(t))-log(P(t-1)). Can anyone please help with the command.

Comment: When writing a question, it is common to make a small reproducible example of code so that others may test your ideas/code. As it stands, nobody knows your code and what you have tried. Give it try, edit your question to add more info to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `diff` and `log`

```
library(xts)
diff(log(MLB))
```

#### data

```
MLB <- structure(c(40.72, 48.66, 47.23, 44.45, 41.82, 44.61, 55.22), .Dim = c(7L, 
1L), index = structure(c(1199145600, 1230768000, 1262304000, 
1293840000, 1325376000, 1356998400, 1388534400), tzone = "UTC",
tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "MLB.Prices"))
```

Comment: This is the output I received...
log(diff(MLB))
           MLB.Prices
2008-01-01         NA
2009-01-01   2.071913
2010-01-01        NaN
2011-01-01        NaN
2012-01-01        NaN
2013-01-01   1.026042
2014-01-01   2.361797

Comment: @AlexaThomas That is correct.  `log` of negative values are NaN as I recall.  When you take the difference between adjacent elements and if the next value is less than the previous, it results in negative values and thus log returns NaN

Comment: @AlexaThomas ok, I think you meant `diff(log(MLB))` and not the other way